# How do I grant a rotation Lambda access to AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, aws-secrets-manager

Using the serverless framework, I am trying to build [a Lambda function that periodically rotates a secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets.html) stored in AWS Secrets Manager.

I am having trouble configuring the roles needed for the Secret Manager to execute the Lambda. In my `serverless.yml` I have defined the following resources:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    RotateKeysRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: rotate-keys-role
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
                  - secretsmanager.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
```

and attach this role to the rotation Lambda like this:

```
functions:
  rotateKeys:
    handler: lambdas.rotate_keys.handler
    role: RotateKeysRole
```

Yet, when I try to set up Secrets Manager to use this Lambda for rotating secrets I will get the following error message:

> Secrets Manager cannot invoke the specified Lambda function. Ensure
>   that the function policy grants access to the principal
>   secretsmanager.amazonaws.com

which puzzles me as this principal is specified. Inspecting the role in the IAM console did not reveal anything that seemed wrong to me.

How do I correctly configure the role setup in this scenario?

Comment: I'm currently trying to configure my credential rotation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59932893/how-to-configure-credential-rotation-in-aws-secret-manager I'm just wondering is Lambda compulsory for configuring the rotation and do you mind describing how you did it in my question, much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The procedure of setting up permissions for a lambda function which rotates AWS Secrets Manager secrets is explained in the docs. [1]

To put it in a nutshell, you need two steps:

- Add a trust policy to the lambda function. This can be achieved using the CloudFormation resource *AWS::Lambda::Permission* in the serverless.yml file. However, it is a little bit tricky to set this up, because you need to depend on the function being created. That is why the *DependsOn* is necessary and its value must be structured as follows: `<function-name-with-first-letter-uppercase>LambdaFunction`.
- Add statements for the lambda function to call the AWS Secrets Manager API to update the secret. In the following example, I added these statements (for the *Single user rotation* case - see docs [1]) to the customer managed policy called *rotateKeysPolicy*.

Note: The function name is referenced in the *DependsOn* attribute. It is also referenced in the condition *StringEquals* and the attribute *FunctionName* as: `arn:aws:lambda:${self:custom.region}:${self:custom.accountId}:function:${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-rotateKeys`. Keep in mind to change them if you change your function name.

Here is how the serverless.yml file should look like:

```
service:
  name: <your-service-name>

provider:
  name: aws
  region: '<your-region>'

custom:
  region: ${self:provider.region}
  accountId: <your-account-id>

resources:
  Resources:
    FunctionRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: basic-function-role
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: rotateKeysPolicy
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - secretsmanager:DescribeSecret
                    - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
                    - secretsmanager:PutSecretValue
                    - secretsmanager:UpdateSecretVersionStage
                  Resource: '*'
                  Condition:
                    StringEquals:
                      'secretsmanager:resource/AllowRotationLambdaArn': "arn:aws:lambda:${self:custom.region}:${self:custom.accountId}:function:${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-rotateKeys"
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                  - secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword
                  Resource: '*'
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                    - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                    - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  Resource: '*'
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole         
    LambdaInvokePermission:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      DependsOn: RotateKeysLambdaFunction
      Properties:
        FunctionName: "arn:aws:lambda:${self:custom.region}:${self:custom.accountId}:function:${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-rotateKeys"
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal: 'secretsmanager.amazonaws.com'

functions:
  rotateKeys:
    handler: lambdas.rotate_keys.handler
    role: FunctionRole
```

You have to replace `<your-service-name>`, `<your-region>`, `<your-account-id>` and upload your rotation code using e.g. the `package -> include` attributes.

Note: There are templates for the lambda function which update the secrets. [2][3]

Please also keep in mind to configure your VPC correctly for the lambda function being able to access the AWS Secrets Manager service over the network. [4]

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-required-permissions.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-create-generic-template.html
[3] https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas
[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotation-network-rqmts.html

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue today. I ran this and it worked for me:

```
aws lambda add-permission \
  --function-name ARN_of_lambda_function \
  --principal secretsmanager.amazonaws.com \
  --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
  --statement-id SecretsManagerAccess
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/troubleshoot_rotation.html

Comment: This does indeed allow me to rotate my secrets successfully, yet I still have no idea how to do this in my serverless.yml file. Are you using serverless as well?

Comment: Indeed - super useful but how to do this not via the cli?

Answer (score 2):

I got this resolved by adding following aws_lambda_permission resource

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "example_permission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowSecretsManagerToInvokeFunction"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = module.moduleName.aws_lambda_function.lambda_handler
  principal     = "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your policy is incorrect.
The service is secretsmanager but the action you defined is sts:AssumeRole which is from AWS Security Token Service.

A full access policy would be:

```
Effect: "Allow"
Action: "secretsmanager:*"
Resource: "*"
```

But you **should** limit the actions and the Resource the lambda can use.
For this you can use the [policy builder](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/policies$new?step=edit) which can be found in IAM->Policies.
[image: Policy builder]

After creating a policy in the editor you can click on the JSON Tab and see the format. Then you need to adapt it to your serverless yaml format.

I hope I can help you!

Dominik

Comment: Wouldn't this allow the  Lambda to use Secrets Manager? I am looking for the inverse scenario where I need to allow Secrets Manager to call my Lambda.