# Secrets Manage: Fail to rotate the secret, cannot invoke the specified Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

Error: **Secrets Manager cannot invoke the specified Lambda function. Ensure that the function policy grants access to the principal secretsmanager.amazonaws.com**

I'm using Secret Manager to store my key for verifying JWTs.
My planned configuration is to rotate deprecate the keys with the following logic:

my secret looks like this:

```
{
  current:'my-current-secret',
  previous:'my-previous-secret',
  alg:'encoding alg',
}
```

*It seemed like overkill to use two secrets and rotating them -- I'm only keeping a memory of the `previous` token to handle fringe cases for a hand-off. If auth fails I'll check if it verifies with the `previous`, if it does it'll return an updated cookie using the `current` key

createSecret:

```
putSecretValue({
      current: getRandomPassword(...),
      previous: getSecretValue(...)['current'],
      alg: env.param ? env.param : getSecretValue(...)['alg']
})
```

I'm not using `setSecret`, `testSecret`, `finishSecret`

I'm not using serverless (I will at some point, but I wanted to familiarize myself w/ AWS/GUI first before short-cutting w/ the CLI)
I've looked at:

- [How do I grant a rotation Lambda access to AWS Secrets Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118962/how-do-i-grant-a-rotation-lambda-access-to-aws-secrets-manager)
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-create-generic-template.html

I can't figure out what IAM setting I'm missing.

When I try to set the rotation lambda:
[image: add rotation]

This flashes (So quickly, I had to record my screen to take a look):
[image: false hope]

And I immediately get the following error:
[image: error msg]

I started by giving the lambda full control of `secrets manager` and `lambdas` to work backwards into minimal controls, but even throwing the kitchen sink at it I couldn't get it to work:

```
{
  "permissionsBoundary": {},
  "roleName": "secrets_manager-role-REDACTED",
  "policies": [
    {
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword",
              "secretsmanager:CreateSecret",
              "secretsmanager:ListSecrets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
          },
          {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:REDACTED:secret:REDACTED"
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "ReadWriteREDACTEDSecret",
      "id": "REDACTED",
      "type": "managed",
      "arn": "arn:aws:iam::REDACTED:policy/ReadWriteREDACTEDSecret"
    },
    {
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "lambda:InvokeFunction",
              "lambda:InvokeAsync"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:REDACTED:function:secrets_manager"
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "invoke_secrets_manager_lambda",
      "id": "REDACTED",
      "type": "managed",
      "arn": "arn:aws:iam::REDACTED:policy/invoke_secrets_manager_lambda"
    },
    {
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:REDACTED:*"
          },
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:REDACTED:log-group:/aws/lambda/secrets_manager:*"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-REDACTED",
      "id": "REDACTED",
      "type": "managed",
      "arn": "arn:aws:iam::REDACTED:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-REDACTED"
    },
    {
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
              "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
              "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
              "cloudformation:GetTemplate",
              "cloudformation:ListStackResources",
              "cloudwatch:*",
              "cognito-identity:ListIdentityPools",
              "cognito-sync:GetCognitoEvents",
              "cognito-sync:SetCognitoEvents",
              "dynamodb:*",
              "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
              "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
              "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
              "events:*",
              "iam:GetPolicy",
              "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
              "iam:GetRole",
              "iam:GetRolePolicy",
              "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
              "iam:ListRolePolicies",
              "iam:ListRoles",
              "iam:PassRole",
              "iot:AttachPrincipalPolicy",
              "iot:AttachThingPrincipal",
              "iot:CreateKeysAndCertificate",
              "iot:CreatePolicy",
              "iot:CreateThing",
              "iot:CreateTopicRule",
              "iot:DescribeEndpoint",
              "iot:GetTopicRule",
              "iot:ListPolicies",
              "iot:ListThings",
              "iot:ListTopicRules",
              "iot:ReplaceTopicRule",
              "kinesis:DescribeStream",
              "kinesis:ListStreams",
              "kinesis:PutRecord",
              "kms:ListAliases",
              "lambda:*",
              "logs:*",
              "s3:*",
              "sns:ListSubscriptions",
              "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
              "sns:ListTopics",
              "sns:Publish",
              "sns:Subscribe",
              "sns:Unsubscribe",
              "sqs:ListQueues",
              "sqs:SendMessage",
              "tag:GetResources",
              "xray:PutTelemetryRecords",
              "xray:PutTraceSegments"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "AWSLambdaFullAccess",
      "id": "REDACTED",
      "type": "managed",
      "arn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaFullAccess"
    }
  ],
  "trustedEntities": [
    "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com",
    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
  ]
}
```

My lambda trust policy is as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com",
          "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After combing through the aws gui for ~10 hours and googling extensively I came across a s/o post for a different resource that linked to the docs saying that a lambda's function policy cannot be set in the gui.

I ran the following command in the cli and everything worked:

```
aws lambda add-permission \
          --function-name secrets_manager \
          --principal secretsmanager.amazonaws.com \
          --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
          --statement-id SecretsManagerAccess
```

**`--function-name secrets_manager` is because my lambda function is named `secrets_manager`**

source:
`https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-create-generic-template.html`

Comment: Sorry to hear that it took you 10 hours :( . Yea Lambda should support updating this function policy in the console.

Comment: Hi @Schalton I wish I could see your answer earlier... I've spent several days on this issue, just wondering if I can use the same command to grant permission if I use the rotation function template for MySQL engine? (link: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRDSMySQLRotationSingleUser/lambda_function.py) I got the same permission error if I configure in Secret Manager console directly, so I'm trying to create rotation function manually by using this template, any suggestions?

Comment: @Cecilia sorry, I don't know about that use case specifically. After I ran into this problem, I started doing way more config setting in the CLI (versus the  console); I'd recommend looking for CLI solutions since we've learned it is more feature rich -- good luck!

If you find a solution please post a Q&A on S/O to help future users (probably me in 6 months haha)

Answer (score 3):

Update for 2023. It looks like a resource-level policy for Lambda functions can now be set in the AWS Console GUI.

Go to your Lambda function, then Configuration > Permissions. Scroll down to the "Resource-based policy statements". Here you can add a permission for an AWS Service (choose Secrets Manager), enter your statement ID, and choose lambda:InvokeFunction for the action. The correct Principal is filled in when you choose the Secrets Manager service.

[image: Lambda - Add permissions - Policy statement]

At least your error in Secrets Manager was more descriptive. All I got was "Failed to rotate the secret for my_function", no additional details.