# How to configure credential rotation in AWS Secret Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, credentials, aws-secrets-manager

I read this [article](https://sanderknape.com/2018/07/manage-custom-secrets-aws-secrets-manager/) about how to implement the credential rotation, I know I could just configure this in 'Edit rotation configuration' option, but the thing is my current secret is in use, and I notice that it says 'Enable automatic rotation - Recommended when your applications are not using this secret yet', how can I enable the rotation then? My database is using RDS Aurora MySQL engine and I want it to rotate every 7 days.

I also read this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_identity-based-policies.html#permissions_grant-admin-actions), does it mean I must have an IAM role with full access to secret manager? Is the Lambda function compulsory for configuring credential rotation?

I also followed this [doc](http://Phase%203:%20Enable%20Rotation%20for%20Your%20Secret), in the Phrase 3, step 4, the screenshot looks different to mine, I don't have the option 'Use the secret that I provided in step 1', I have something like this:
[image]
In the screenshot above, it says 'Use this option if you are storing a superuser.' How do I know if I'm storing a superuser?

I'm new to AWS, messing around for a whole morning and read lots of documents, still a bit confused, can someone tell me what's the best way to do this, can someone point me to a step-by-step tutorial or something like that, any suggestions will be appreciated.